# How appropriate is it to follow up after a job interview if you forgot to ask about the next steps during the interview?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I interviewed at a company towards the end of last week and I believe the interview went well. But during the end I forgot to ask the hiring manager about the next steps or when I can hear back from them. I sent a thank you note to the recruiter the same day. Would it be appropriate to follow up with the recruiter after 3 or 4 days regarding the status or how soon can I hear back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up.

This is part of the recruiter's job. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Is it alright to ask to understand the timeline?

Comment: Is it alright to ask to understand the timeline so that I don't overthink it atleast until then? I edited the question appropriately

Comment: Don't overthink asking questions. If you have a question, ask it. If you have questions about the interview process (timeline, steps, etc.), ask. If you have questions about the benefits, make-up of the team, technologies used, salary, etc. Ask. They may not know the answer or have a firm answer, but generally asking isn't harmful.